# How to rename files: picture.jpg.~1~ to picture_~1~.jpg

Tags: backup, sed, rename, mv

I have say 30000 files of this type: picture.jpg.~12~

They are remnants of a backup (mv  -v --backup=numbered ...).

I needed to switch the extensions to: picture.~12~.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found this solution finally which might inspire you in This Long Dark Covid-time of the Soul.

```
ls *~*~* | sed -n "s/\(.*\)\.\([^.]*\).\(~[0-9]*~\)$/mv  -v --backup=numbered  \"\0\" \"\1_\3.\2\"/p" >switch_extensions.sh
chmod +x switch_extensions.sh
./switch_extensions.sh > switch_extensions.log
```

The first line produces commands:

```
mv  -v --backup=numbered  "Trombone.tif.~10~" "Trombone_~10~.tif"
```

The second line makes it executable, the third is renaming while creating a log file. Then swiftly comes relief from the dark soul ruminations. Try it!

You might know a smarter solution, so let brains storm!
:-)

Comment: `mmv '*.jpg.*' '#1.#2.jpg'`

Comment: +1, @xerostomus, nice challenge :-)

Comment: @bac0n, great command for this task. I would have manipulated the file name parts with bash parameter expansion methods and then done a mv command, but this is so much simpler. When looking at the link in your comment at the question, I saw that I already upvoted it years ago, but forgot about it :-P

Comment: @xerostomus: Please note: [Why *not* parse `ls`?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls)

Comment: @Cyrus Of course, I run detox first.  I do not tolerate much freedom among file names. :-)

Comment: @bacOn - Thanks, I did not know it.